# Pause Screen Design iOS game

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, usability

My game has a pause screen which doubles as the main title screen with high scores.  It is semi-transparent so the user can see what state the game-round was in.  They can see the last message such as "Win" or "Loss". In the case of an interruption or pause they see "Redo". My game already handles interruptions gracefully, saving state and restoring last round so that the user can try again.

Question; when the user closes the app (hits home button) or if the app is interrupted with an incoming phone call during game-play, **when the app comes back into the foreground should I show the pause screen or should I take them back to the game?** Another way to phrase this question would be, should the home button and the pause button behave virtually the same for game-play interruption?   (I presume that if the user were in a sub-screen, non-game-play, they would be taken back to that sub-screen).

Question 2; What does it mean to pause?  I believe all sounds should cease but can I get away with keeping some minimal animation going?  I do know that if the app were to go into the background that the OpenGL ES 2 animation would have to cease.  **Do you think users would prefer to have no animations during pause?**  I question the extent to which battery life should influence the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a very subjective question. I'll try to give you some input.

I would say the good rule of thumb is: Will it affect your game play if you don't pause the game? For example, if your game is a chess or sudoku game, it wouldn't really matter if you pause the game when the user exit to home screen. However if your game is an action game that each mili second is very important and will decide whether the user will win, then in that case you would need to pause the game.

What does it mean to pause: It depends on your implementation. It can be anything you want. You can even continue the animation in the background if you want. This is all up to you.